# How do we implement controllerclassnamehandlermapping using spring annotattion

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a spring MVC application with two controller classes as given below.

```
package test;
@Controller
public class MyTestController{

      @RequestMapping()
      public ModelAndView getTestView(){
           //create model and view
           //return model and view
      }
}

package test;
@Controller
public class MyTestDemoController{

      @RequestMapping()
      public ModelAndView getTestDemoView(){
           //create model and view
           //return model and view
      }
}
```

I use '`<mvc:annotation-driven />`' & '`<context:component-scan base-package="test.controller" />`' to identify the controllers.

My intention is to invoke getTestView() when i hit the application with a url similar to http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyTest.htm 
and simillarly
getTestDemoView() when i hit the application with a url similar to http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyTestDemo.htm

i tried putting this in spring app servlet, but it dint worked out.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
```

can you suggest me a way to implement ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping using spring annotation?

Comment: Have you configured dispatcher servlet in web.xml?

Comment: yes i have. where i have mapped the url *.htm to dispatcher servlet

Comment: apply @RequestMapping("/MyTest")  above your method

Comment: i dont want any trace of URL in my code. That is why i decided to go with ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping. something like this 'http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-controllerclassnamehandlermapping-example/'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to map root to both controllers. Put @RequestMapping("someValue") at the top of your class, above class definition, and go to localhost:8080/someValue to see the response.

Comment: i want dispatcher servlet to decide the controller based on controller class name. say, MyTest.htm should point to MyTestController

Answer (score 0):

You are using extension ".htm"  and expecting naming convention to work automatically. I think removing extension may work.

As per "http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-controllerclassnamehandlermapping-example/"
if you are using extension then write below in your configuration

or follow naming convention.

Regards,
Krish